# Zoom leaflet map to default in Rshiny

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

Is there anyway to add a layer control or button to reset map and go back the initial position. For example, when in the you are exploring a map and zooming in, and then you want to zoom out to get back to the initial stage.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

outline <- quakes[chull(quakes$long, quakes$lat),]

output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({ leaflet(quakes) %>%
  # Base groups
  addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.Toner", group = "Toner") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite", group = "Toner Lite") %>%
  # Overlay groups
  addCircles(~long, ~lat, ~10^mag/5, stroke = F, group = "Quakes") %>%
  addPolygons(data = outline, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat,
              fill = F, weight = 2, color = "#FFFFCC", group = "Outline") %>%
  # Layers control
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "Toner", "Toner Lite"),
    overlayGroups = c("Quakes", "Outline"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
    )

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this without any javascript code by using the `leafletProxy` and the `setView` functions to change the map when the a button is clicked.

Here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  actionButton("reset_button", "Reset view")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  initial_lat = -23.079
  initial_lng = 178.15
  initial_zoom = 4

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({ leaflet(quakes) %>% 
                                    setView(lat = initial_lat, lng = initial_lng, zoom = initial_zoom) %>%
                                    addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
                                    addProviderTiles("Stamen.Toner", group = "Toner") %>%
                                    addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite", group = "Toner Lite")})                                 


  observe({
    input$reset_button
    leafletProxy("mymap") %>% setView(lat = initial_lat, lng = initial_lng, zoom = initial_zoom)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: And what if you want the default view. Depending on the markers. Instead of initializing initial_lat and initial_long ?

Comment: @celianou, You can't use `leafletProxy` for it, but you can have a reference to your reset button inside the `renderLeaflet` block, and then use `leafet(...) %>% clearBounds()` to reset to the initial settings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Have a look at the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) of leaflet.

Methods for Modifying Map State
`setView()`

> Sets the view of the map (geographical center and zoom) with the given > animation options.

So what I would do is include an [actionButton](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/actionbutton-demo.html) in the `ui.R` with an `observeEvent()` which activates the `.js` function. How shiny can communicate with `.js` files you can read [here](https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/).

An example which you have to adapt to your code:

```
ui.R
actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
p("Click the button to update the view.")

server.R
    observeEvent(input$goButton, {
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "myCallbackHandler", Yourlatlng) //send to .js code snippet
})


//I would create a www file in the folder where server.R and ui.R is. By default shiny looks into this folder
 .js file
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("myCallbackHandler",function(Yourlatlng) {
var latlng = Yourlatlng;
setView(latlng, center,...) //check documentation for your specifcations
});
```